# Sonata User Bundle - redirect loop

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I have installed both FOSUserBundle and Sonata Admin bundle

First FOSUserBundle worked perfect, with both profile, login and logout.
Now with Sonata Admin bundle, I can CRUD my entities.

Now I wanted them integrated with login to my backend.

Now when I go to /admin/dashboard it redirects to /admin/login and then a infinity redirect loop.

I have properly messed up the security, and I really dont understand it that well.

security.yml : https://gist.github.com/lsv/4740268

routing.yml : https://gist.github.com/lsv/4740284

config.yml : https://gist.github.com/lsv/4740291

dev.log : https://gist.github.com/lsv/4740301

Can somebody help?

Comment: I played a bit with access_control and even removed it in my security file, but still just redirect loop

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
- { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/admin/login-check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

to security.yml

Comment: further to this, these rules should be above your main /admin/ lockout rule